# How can I create a graph of Nginx responses by HTTP status code?

Tags: web-server, nginx

I'm looking to create a graph *somewhat* similar to this:

[alt text http://static.k5-storitve.net/site_media/images/plugins/51-1170621310-ra.mahune.org-nginx_request-month.png](http://static.k5-storitve.net/site_media/images/plugins/51-1170621310-ra.mahune.org-nginx_request-month.png)

But instead of graphing requests, graph responses, with a line for each HTTP response code (200 OK, 404 Not Found, 500 Server Error, etc).

Creating the graph isn't the issue (use RRDtool, Server Density or something similar), but how can I best retrieve this information from Nginx?

Unfortunately, this data isn't available on the page generated by [NginxHttpStubStatusModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpStubStatusModule). If it was, this would be pretty easy.

Comment: Here's a nicer sample of what you're asking for (but alas, the code is Apache): http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/http_status/details

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the access log for this.

Comment: And this task may be simplified by defining your own log format.